# Auto Synchronization of Entity Bean

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Could you please solve my tiny problem. I have an entity bean name ABC which is 
           created from database and table name in abc. The entity bean is generated properly
           through tools that I have used but now what happened I have added few more column 
           to the table and now I want these newly added column to the EntityBean. How can I 
           do that?

Comment: A sidenote: EJB 3 doesn't have any notion of entities. That part is called JPA now.

Comment: You should do it the opposite way around. Define your Entitiy Bean, properly annotate the fields and / or the class, and let your build tools auto create the new columns.

Comment: What JPA provider are you using e.g OpenJPA or Hibernate etc.In your persistance.xml you need to turn on a property called Schema-update to true. The documentation of your JPA provider will have information on this property.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the cleanest way would be to add the fields and mappings yourself. That way you have full control on how the mapping is defined.

Edit: you might have a look at the hibernate tools for code generation: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#codegenarchitecture

Please note that I'd still advise to do the changes to entities as well as to the database yourself.